# What is the default encoding type for the network in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, encode

When I sent a request, I found that it was 404. Then I went to catch the package and found that my url was encoded.
I know that it is a question about coding.

```
const http = require('http');

http.get({
    hostname: 's3plus.sankuai.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/v1/mss_0ddf9b250a1b4db28fb1d9ad764b2853/test/样图.jpg',
    agent: false  
  }, (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

[image]

[image]

It was encoded to 7\376.jpg

I read the Node Source of JavaScript about net/http, but I can't find any thing useful for me.

I want to know what default encoding of Node?

Comment: It looks like it just used the low byte of the character value.  To get a correctly-formatted URL path, provide the result of `encodeURI('/v1/mss_0ddf9b250a1b4db28fb1d9ad764b2853/test/样图.jpg')` as the `path` member of the `options` argument.

Comment: @ottomeister yeah, I know how to solve this problem, but I want to know the default coding type for Node. The above encoding is not utf-8 or gb2312 encoding